# How do I get the key or coordinates of a Marker in react-native-maps in onPress?

Tags: javascript, events, react-native, react-native-maps

I'm using [react-native-maps](https://github.com/airbnb/react-native-maps/) to render a MapView with several Markers. I want to perform some actions and animations when a user clicks on a marker. For that, I am binding a function (e.g., onMarkerPress) to each Marker's onPress. The problem I'm running into is that I cannot figure out how to find out which marker is triggering the function. Is there any way to get a reference to the marker/identifying key prop? Even the coordinates would do as I can use those to lookup the marker.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found 2 ways to do that.
Most probably the first one is the best choice:

**1. pass the info you need about the marker as a second argument to the bind of _onMarkerPress as below:**

```
render() {

    return (
        <View>
            <Text>MySupaFancyMap</Text>
            <MapView
                style={styles.map}
                region={this.state.region}
                onRegionChangeComplete={this._onRegionChangeComplete.bind(this)}
            >
                <MapView.Marker
                    coordinate={this.state.marker.latlng}
                    title={this.state.marker.title}
                    description={this.state.marker.description}
                    onPress={this._onMarkerPress.bind(this, this.state.marker)}
                />
            </MapView>
        </View>
    );
}
_onMarkerPress (markerData) {
    alert(JSON.stringify(markerData));
}
```

In my case this.state.marker is an object like this:

```
       {
            latlng: {
                latitude: REGION.latitude,
                longitude: REGION.longitude
            },
            title:'MyHouse',
            weather: '26 Celsius'

        }
```

**2. extract the info you need from the event info like this:**

```
 <MapView>
//codes here
onPress={this._onMarkerPress.bind(this)}
>
 
<MapView.Marker
       coordinate={this.state.marker.latlng}         
/>
<MapView>
```

and with:

```
_onMarkerPress (mkr) {
    console.warn(mkr.nativeEvent.coordinate);
}
```

I would definitely go with the first solution.
More details about Markers here:
https://github.com/airbnb/react-native-maps/blob/master/docs/marker.md

Note: as a best practice it is recommended that you don't have binds at render. Better solutions are to add them in the constructor like this:

```
constructor (props) {
  super(props);
  this._onMarkerPress = this._onMarkerPress.bind(this);
}
```

or use the arrow function. When I wrote the answer I didn't know about this.

Comment: Are you sure about that second method? After reading through issues, I saw the same suggestion. However, coordinate simply gives me undefined when I try it just like what [others reported here](https://github.com/airbnb/react-native-maps/issues/580). As for the first method, I figured out how to do that as well this morning since I saw no answer. So it definitely works. I'm still curious as to why I can't get the coordinates though.

Comment: I tested the second method and it worked perfectly. Try _onMarkerPress (mkr) {
    console.warn(Object.keys(mkr));
}. This is how I found the second method.

Comment: nativeEvent is there, but the only keys inside of it are id, action, and target. What version of react-native-maps are you using? I'm on 0.13.0 as it's the only one that works with React Native >= 0.40. Perhaps there's a major regression in this version?

Comment: I have  "dependencies": {
    "react": "15.4.2",
    "react-native": "0.41.2",
    "react-native-maps": "^0.12.4"
  }

Comment: Ok, had some time today to setup a working environment that uses 0.12.4 and was able to confirm that coordinate is a key in that version. So it looks like 0.13.0 has a major regression which means I should either downgrade my react-native and react-native-maps versions, or I use the first solution listed. Thanks for your help.